# Django return " 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR" when $.post a utf-8 string

Tags: jquery, django

I met a issue that django always return "500 internal server error" when I tried to post a utf-8 string(e.g. Chinese string). But I tried to post a ascii string, it looks OK. Furthermore, It works OK on my own Archlinux machine, but it can't work on another CentOS server. How can I avoid this issue?

template:

```
 $(".palcesubm").click(function(){
        var location = $('#detail_address').val()
        $.post('/wechat/locate/select/create/',
                {'location':location}, function(){
                window.location = "/wechat/locate/baidu/";
        })
    });
```

view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_location(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_to_response('create_location.html')
    else:
        print request.POST.get('location')
        request.session['location'] = request.POST.get('location')
        return HttpResponse('success')
```

Comment: Can you turn on ```DEBUG``` and get the stacktrace for the error?

Comment: I've trun on the DEBUG, but there is no error in the console.

Comment: does your `print` statement in the view get executed ? Also, sessions are not enabled by default. You need to activate the middleware in order to use it. Make sure you have it on.. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#enabling-sessions

Comment: Yes， I've enable the session in the middleware, and the [print] statement can't show on the console . But it is ok on my own machine. BTW, server and my machine share the same code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably getting an UnicodeEncodeError because

```
request.POST.get('location')
```

returns an unicode object. When you try to print it, Python tries to encode it using the 'ascii' codec and fails because it contains non-ascii chars.

If you really want to print it, use:

```
print request.POST.get('location').encode('utf-8')
```

EDIT: more info about encodings in Python: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally， I find a magic way to solve this problem . I just comment the print statement in view. But I'm still not sure for its reason.

Comment: It's because it's probably expecting an string only containing ASCII characters, but the value contains unicode characters. Because of that, it'll fail to encode it.